# Android Dropbox API file download

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am currently working on an android app that is to support the android dropbox api. I have got it working so that it sends a file from the android sd card to a dropbox folder. I then later on need to be able to download this file and save it to the phone sd card again.

How can I download the file from Dropbox and save it to the device, there is very little to no documentation about the android api.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: From your API variable use api.putFile("dropbox", "/location/on/dropbox", path/on/sdcard); Hope that this helps

Comment: one more doubt please, how should i make consumer_key and consumer_secret unique for all users, because in my app another user login showing network error? why so

Comment: From how I understand it, I believe when you login to DropBox the DropBox server returns the consumer key and consumer secret so it should be unique for each user attempting to login to DropBox, the network error may be something else. I did find that when debugging it would randomly stop working saying it couldn't connect but then after leaving it would work. Think possibly dropbox stopped you from logging in too many times so maybe this might be your problem

Comment: how can i make my app for all users, that means everybody can login, should i change consumer_key and consumer_secret

Comment: You need to log in to your DropBox development account and go to My Apps then apply for production status by filling in a form. DropBox will review and if they approve it they will send you an email and you will get the required keys to be added to the program that allows any dropbox login not just developer account

Comment: Can you please tell me how to download images from dropbox folder to my SD card

Comment: I belive its api.getFile("dropbox", "/Directory_On_DropBox/file.ext", null);

Comment: @Bordy api.getFile() showing this bug:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed, what is the solution please

Comment: can you please provide me the code to add a file from sd card to drop box?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana you would be better off asking this another question (if one doesn't already exist) as it is not related to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

    BufferedInputStream br = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

    try {
        if (!localFile.exists()) {
            localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
        }

        FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);
        br = new BufferedInputStream(fd.is);
        bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while (true) {
        read = br.read(buffer);
        if (read <= 0) {
        break;
        }
        bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        //in finally block:
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Source: http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=23189&replies=5#post-159521

Answer (score 0):

if try this link , [Download file from Dropbox and save it into SDCARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566884/download-file-from-dropbox-and-save-it-into-sdcard)  really help full to download the any type of file through drop box

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

    BufferedInputStream br = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

    try {
        if (!localFile.exists()) {
            localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
        }

        FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);
        br = new BufferedInputStream(fd.is);
        bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while (true) {
        read = br.read(buffer);
        if (read <= 0) {
        break;
        }
        bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        //in finally block:
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It will may be working for you.