# Download file from Dropbox and save it into SDCARD

Tags: android, dropbox

Am really frustated now..I want to download a file from Dropbox and save that file into SDCARD..and I got the code as:

```
     private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

BufferedInputStream br = null;
BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

try {
    if (!localFile.exists()) {
        localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
    }

    FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);
    **br = new BufferedInputStream(fd.is);**
    bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int read;
    while (true) {
    read = br.read(buffer);
    if (read <= 0) {
    break;
    }
    bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
} finally {
    //in finally block:
    if (bw != null) {
        bw.close();
    }
    if (br != null) {
        br.close();
    }
}

return true;
```

}

Here I am getting an error on br=new BufferedInputStream line..Pls help

Comment: Please also copy/paste the error and stacktrace.

Comment: I have copy pasted this code from link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180926/android-dropbox-api-file-download...And In my code It is not recognising "fd.is"

Comment: Are you sure that `fd.is != null`?

Comment: Do you know any other method to download a file from dropbox?? beacuse I have copy pasted that code and it is not working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the way:

```
      File file= new File("/sdcard/New_csv_file.csv");
      OutputStream out= null;
      boolean result=false;
      try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
               DropboxFileInfo info = mApi.getFile("/photos/New_csv_file.csv", null, out, null);
               Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + info.getMetadata().rev);
               Intent JumpToParseCSV=new Intent(context,ParseCSV.class);
                JumpToParseCSV.putExtra("FileName", file.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.i("path", "FileName"+ file.getAbsolutePath());
                 ((Activity) context).finish();
                context.startActivity(JumpToParseCSV);
                result=true;
            } catch (DropboxException e) {
               Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while downloading.");
               file.delete();
               result=false;
            }


    return result;
```

Thanks all....

Comment: what does ParseCvs class do here?