# I want to download a file from from dropbox to my sdcard.

Tags: android, download, dropbox

I found a solution to this at this link : [Download file from Dropbox and save it into SDCARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566884/download-file-from-dropbox-and-save-it-into-sdcard) But I dont know what is FileDownload class here. And what is api object?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the dropbox core api.
Just look at the developer site from dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

Comment: Sorry, there is no class named FileDownload.

Comment: FileDownload is a costum class, you dont need it. Just take a look at the acceptable answear orthe dropbox tutorial