# How to download images and pdf files from dropbox to my android application

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Hi I am working on Android application which has dropbox implementation where I want to get the images and pdf files from dropbox to my android application to send to the server.Can anyone please example or source code?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the [Dropbox files Get API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET). Sample code is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180926/android-dropbox-api-file-download).

This is not a site where you post a question and people will come around giving you code. You will have to explain what you have tried and what have you failed at, only then will people be able to help you.