# Downloading Multiple files or folder from dropbox in android ?

Tags: android, dropbox

So far I've successfully integrated Dropbox API with my project. For that I've been using an example program that is given in Dropbox SDK. From the way i can download(random Picture) and upload files easily. My question is,   How can we download a folder or multiple files at a time from their dropbox account? . Additionally When i click on the download button it randomly chosen one image file then displaying, instead of doing this i want to download all image files or particular folder. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180926/android-dropbox-api-file-download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sync API works by downloading files on-demand when you open them. So just open all the files you're trying to read.

Comment: How to do that ? we can only pass the file name one by one . You mean to do this recursively?. On the other hand if user doesn't know the file name means how can we able to download only use of path.

Comment: You can just list the files in that path and open them as needed.

Comment: could you please post a snippet of code. It will really helpful for me.

Comment: Take a look at `listFolder`: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileSystem.listFolder. Just call that and loop through the files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. can we use both the core API and sync API in same project? when i use sync API i got dex compiler error. That is more than one dex file created.

Comment: If you search on the Dropbox API forum, you'll see some discussion of using both in the same project. It's possible but requires renaming some things to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please go through following code, may be this is helpful to you.

```
private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

    BufferedInputStream br = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

    try {
        if (!localFile.exists()) {
            localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
        }

        FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);
        br = new BufferedInputStream(fd.is);
        bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while (true) {
        read = br.read(buffer);
        if (read <= 0) {
        break;
        }
        bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        //in finally block:
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

For more information please check the [`source`](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=23189&replies=5#post-159521).

Comment: Before accepting your answer i wanna to be clearly understanding the code first. By using this code we can download a single file or entire folder or all available files on the mentioned path?. FileDownload class is predefined in dropbox API or we have to create it manually? I know this could be silly question even though i should be clear on my doubts.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be relevant. (I would guess it's using the Core API and not the Sync API?)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get all FILES and FOLDER from drop box, then simply copy and paste this code in your project and see the result. It will help you a lot.

```
    String mPath="/";  //You can change the path here to specific FOLDER
Entry dirent = null;
 try 
   {
      dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);            
    } 
 catch (DropboxException e)
   {
     System.out.println("Error Detail "+e.getMessage());
   }
```

> //Perform a Loop and retrieve all FILES and FOLDER from the PATH

```
     for (Entry ent: dirent.contents)
     {
       String name = ent.fileName();                           
       System.out.println("My File in Folder "+name);                        
      }
```